# How to create a single application from multiple Android projects

Tags: android, packaging

I am developing a project where i have to create several Android projects but at the end i have to package all the projects in to one single application.is there anyway to do it?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 3):

Create Multiple APKs, and remove the Launcher category from the activities that you don't need to show up in the apps list. For one of the project, there would be a launcher.

But, the problem with this approach is that, users will have to install all the apks or, you can make your main apk handle this for you by saying,

"Hey, if you want this feature, go to the market and download this app" and direct them to the apks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your sub project to library project, then refer to them from your main project. Here are details http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html